# How to add adview into nth user of the dynamically adding listviews in android

Tags: android, list, kotlin, set, adview

i am developing an kotlin app in which there is a layout which contains 3 rows in a list view and each row contains a list of imageview with names. I want to set adview after every 12th users view.  I don't know how to add adview in dynamically rows in list view please help me. i have attached the screenshot which explains my question.[image]